# How fix rails errors installation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railsinstaller

When Running this command

```
rails new test --api
```

I found this error

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates/config/environments/test.rb.tt:10: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input (SyntaxError));  if spring_install?
```

what is the solution??

Comment: What does `ruby -v` return?

Comment: the version of rub is 2.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this error face in 2.5.0 version ,
so you can install ruby 2.5.3

```
rbenv install -l
```

this will tell you the versions of ruby like that

```
2.5.0
2.5.1
2.5.2
2.5.3
2.5.4
2.5.5
2.5.6
2.5.7
```

then run this

```
rbenv install 2.5.3
rbenv global 2.5.3
gem install rails
```